# Gif Xamarin forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gif

I know that xamarin forms currently support playing gif.
I've already tried the link https://github.com/jfversluis/AnimatedGifForms/
But It seems to work only for the gifs with the type in the example, I've tried another gif and it can not load on android.
It works perfectly on the IOS.
There are any config that I can do for playing gif in xamarin forms
I'm using Xamarin.form 4.6, and the latest Xamarin.Essential 1.5.3

Comment: Does the gif work if you show it in a WebView?

Comment: Gif is normal, I can run it on Web, sao webview is obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows) control to load gif in Xamarin.forms.

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Image Source="sample.gif" IsAnimationPlaying="True"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

> Starting and stopping is controlled through IsAnimationPlaying.
> Originally we were going to use Start and Stop methods but all these
> did was set IsAnimationPlaying to true or false respectively. This way
> it can also be started and stopped via Binding!!

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Gif-Xamarin.forms) and you can check.

Refer: [Gif Animation Support](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7330)

**Update**:

Use [Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms/) to load:

```
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"

<StackLayout>

    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Source="blue.gif" />

</StackLayout>
```

Don't forget to `CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);` in `MainActivity`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");

    CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Comment: It's weird because I can run some gif on android also, but some is not so maybe it depends on size of the gif file or other setting ?

Comment: Can you please share us a "gif" which you can't run in Android?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8Mma9YPVi5pSOoW0pCSirEgeNwHg0QU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link of the gif, you can check it out

Comment: Yes, I test the gif and it works well in iOS while not in Android. I get a OutOfMemoryError when I run it in Android. The workaround I found is that you can use [Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms/) to load that gif. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: If my answer helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: IsAnimation running when I'm using it ?

Comment: Yes, I have test on my side and the gif works well.

Comment: It was a regular GIF image but ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage worked for me. Normal ff:CachedImage was crashing.